# Invalid cast from 'WinRT.IInspectable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Windows.Storage.IStorageFile]'

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, casting, windows-runtime

Why does the following Desktop UWP (or WinUI or WinRT? I get confused by the terminology) code compile but throw an exception?

```cs
var folder = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"path\to\folder");
var files  = await folder.GetFilesAsync(); //IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>)

//Exception: Invalid cast from 'WinRT.IInspectable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Windows.Storage.IStorageFile]'.
var l1 = ((IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.IStorageFile>) files).ToList(); //Even crashes if we add e.g. .Select(_=>42) in-between.
```

Note the cast from `StorageFile` to `IStorageFile` (a more nasty bug, which is what I had, is a method taking a list of the latter). Is there something wrong with casting to interfaces in this context, or is this a bug? Normally it works fine, e.g. `((IStorageFile) files[0]).Name`.

This only happens when using C#/WinRT on Desktop. Steps to reproduce:

1. Download the [WinUI 3 Project Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Microsoft-WinUI.WinUIProjectTemplates) extension
2. Create a new C# "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI in Desktop)" via the template (two projects will be created, one for the code, one for the package)
3. Possibly: edit the non-package project file to make sure it lists the correct  `TargetFramework` for me it lists `net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0` while I only have 10.0.19041.0 installed. <s>I guess I'll report this as a bug in a moment.</s> [Seems to be already reported: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4062)]
4. Add the following code to e.g. `OnLauched` in `App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var files  = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
        _ = ((IReadOnlyList<IStorageFile>) files).ToList();
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException ex)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }
});
```

5. Run the package project (enabling break on CLR exceptions recommended)
6. Observe the `InvalidCastException` in `DynamicInterfaceCastableHelpers.IsInterfaceImplemented`

Comment: I have tested the code provided by you, but it works successfully. I couldn’t reproduce the exception, could you please provide us a [mcve] by OneDrive or GitHub?

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Apparently this only happens in C#/WinRT on Desktop. I added reproduction steps above. I guess this means that it is probably a bug; should I report it? I presume it may also happen with other interfaces.

Comment: The code could work well in C# UWP project. The exception about invalid cast may be relative with **WinUI 3.0**. The **WinUI** team is actively answering **WinUI** questions in [WinUI GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues). You could try to submit your questions there.

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4111)